# APC Smart-UPS 1000VA - command file won't get executed

Tags: windows, batch-file, ups

I've got this old piece - http://goo.gl/5M37Sc, working reliably so far, but it has one big problem: command file when power is down won't run.

Everything seems to be configured correctly, but when power is down, no email notification is sent nor my "test.bat" file is executed.

this is from the manual:

```
Using and Troubleshooting Command Files 
Follow these steps to use and test command files. 

Create the .cmd or .bat file and insert it into the cmdfiles folder of PowerChute Business Edition.

Click Where are these files located? to find the location of that folder. (The default folder is “cmdfiles”). See Configure Shutdown Sequence above.

Only command files that are located in the PowerChute command-file folder can be chosen and executed.
In the command file, if you are running an executable file (.exe), use @START, e.g., @START "" "C:\testdir\ myfile.exe"

If you have several lines in your command file, it is possible that some might not execute properly. Try using a single-line command file to call a multiple-line command file if this happens.
If a test fails:
Go to Windows Services and right-click on the Agent service, PBE Agent, and choose Properties.
Click on the Log On tab.Enable the desktop interaction.

If the command file is executing commands to another computer, the local system account here does not have the proper rights. In this case, you should log on as another account that does have rights; specify the account and password in this dialog.

Note: The log on account should have a password that does not expire. This is because passwords here will not automatically update when they are changed elsewhere.

Stop the Agent service and restart it. Retest the command file through PowerChute.
If the command file is still not running, try a simple command file for a test, as shown below. 

Create a folder on the C drive for this test and call it apctest. When you execute it, the single line below in a command file should create a file in apctest named cmdtest.txt. That file should have recorded the time of the test. 
time /T >> C:\apctest\cmdtest.txt
```

I've done all things mentioned, but still, my properly registered test.bat file won't get executed. Anyone has similar experience?

I've also tried to run the file in powerchute console configuration dialog via test button.[image: powerchute software command test] Even this way is not working.